# Drools, How to disable forward chaining?

Tags: drools, rule-engine

I am using Drools rule engine and I was wondering if it was possible to define when a rule can be executed. For example:

If executing a rule A leads to executing 10 rules B1 to B10, **is it possible to choose to execute only one of the Bi rules as a result of rule A??**

An example would be :

```
rule "Rule A"
When
$var : Data(value>10)
then
doSmthg();
Event e = new Event();
insert(e);
end;
```

```
rule "Rule B"
When
$var : Data(range >100)
then
doSmthg();
Event e = new Event();
insert(e);
end;
```

```
rule "Rule C"
When
$e : Event()
then
doSmthg();
end;
```

Firing Rule A would lead to the execution of rule C.
Firing Rule B would lead to the execution of rule C.

Is there a way for me to make it so that rule C won't be fired even after rule A is executed? At the same time, firing B should still lead to the execution of rule C.

EDIT:
I have other rules that I need to be fired if Rule A is executed for example :

```
rule "Rule D"
When
$e : Event()
then
doSmthgElse();
end;
```

so in this case, I just want to disable Rule C from being fired without altering my other rules.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64551325/drools-how-to-disable-forward-chaining

Comment: Just remove the 'insert' from Rule A.

Comment: I can't do that since I have other rules that need to be fired if rule A is true. Only rule C shouldn't be be fired after rule A.

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering subsequent rules by inserting data into working memory. If you don't want a rule to trigger a 'downstream' rule, don't insert the data. Or, alternatively, update the downstream rule to not trigger on the condition.

---

Consider these three rules, which are the same as yours but with syntax cleaned up and indentations fixed.

```
rule "Rule A"
when
  Data( value>10 )
then
  doSmthg();
  insert(new Event());
end

rule "Rule B"
when
  Data(range > 100)
then
  doSmthg();
  insert(new Event());
end

rule "Rule C"
when
  $e : Event()
then
  doSmthg();
end
```

Let's assume your input is `Data( value = 100, range = 500 )`. This is what will happen:

1. Rule A will hit because the condition `value > 10` is met.
2. Rule B will hit because the condition `range > 100` is met.
3. Rule C will hit twice because there are two instances of Event in working memory (one added by Rule A, one added by Rule B.)

Per your question, we don't want Rule C to fire because of Rule A in this condition. To do this, we need to change Rule A to not trigger Rule C. This is simple: remove the `insert(new Event())` from the right hand side of Rule A.

```
rule "New Rule A"
when
  Data( value > 10 )
then
  doSmthg();
  // No insert!
end
```

Rule B will still trigger because its condition (range > 100) is still met and it still inserts the Event instance into working memory.

---

Alternatively if what you're *actually* trying to do is have both A and B trigger C, but only to trigger C once, you can do that by inserting a semaphor into working memory to indicate that C is fired.

Here is an example:

```
rule "Rule A"
when
  Data( value>10 )
then
  doSmthg();
  insert(new Event());
end

rule "Rule B"
when
  Data(range > 100)
then
  doSmthg();
  insert(new Event());
end

rule "Rule C"
when
  not( EventTriggered() )
  $e : Event()
then
  doSmthg();
  insert( new EventTriggered() )
end
```

For the same input ( `Data( value = 50, range = 500 )` ) this is what will happen:

1. Rule A will insert Event into working memory
2. Rule B will insert Event into working memory
3. Rule C will trigger from one of these Events. It will insert an instance of EventTriggered into working memory.
4. Rule C will **not** trigger a second time because the `not()` condition is not satisfied.

Using this setup, an input of `Data( value = 5, range = 500 )` will still trigger Rule C via B:

1. Rule A will NOT fire (condition not met, value <= 10)
2. Rule B will fire, Event inserted into working memory
3. Rule C will fire.

And further, an input of `Data( value = 50, range = 0)` will also trigger Rule C via A:

1. Rule A will fire, Event inserted into working memory
2. Rule B will NOT fire (condition not met, range <= 100)
3. Rule C will fire.

---

Which solution you choose depends on what your *actual* requirements are.

If your requirement is that Rule A should never trigger Rule C, then the first solution (removing the `insert` statement) is the way to go.

If your requirement is that both Rule A and Rule B should trigger Rule C, but only once, then the second solution is the way to go.

Comment: My requirement is that Rule C should only be triggered by Rule B but I need rule A to remain as it is since it can lead to the execution of other rules. This is just an example by the way. what I'm looking for is a way to control when a rule can allow other rules to trigger it without altering the other rules, only the rule in question

Comment: N​​​​​​o​​​​​​​.​​​​​​​​​​​​ You have to write your rule so that it doesn't trigger the rule you don't want it to trigger. You can look into activation groups possibly, but that's fundamentally not the question you asked.